# Select2 Ajax Selected Data Value

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to ask how to select default value from ajax to select2? My ajax code:

```
// Customer
$('.shipper').select2({
    placeholder: "Choose Shipper",
    selectionTitleAttribute: false,
    ajax: {
        url: 'getCustomer.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                filter_name: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                    return {id: obj.customer_id, text: obj.name};
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        return callback({id: "<?php echo $data['customerId']; ?>", text: '<?php echo $shipper['name']; ?>'});
    }
});
```

While my PHP code to fetch data is like this:

```
<?php

include('config.php');
$json = array();

if (isset($_GET['filter_name'])) {
    $clientId = $_GET['filter_name'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM m_customer WHERE c_name LIKE '%$clientId%' AND c_status > 0 ORDER BY c_name ASC LIMIT 0,10";
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM m_customer WHERE c_status > 0 ORDER BY c_name ASC LIMIT 0,10";
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $json[] = array(
        'customer_id' => $row['c_id'],
        'name' => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($row['c_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
    );
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I'm creating update page for my PHP files. So I need this select2 is selected from my database. That's why I get data from database then try to set to `initSelection`. It's already shows up and selected. But when I press save button (and look at my code from inspect element), the select doesn't have value. So it failed to save (screenshot attached)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have weird solution:

I put the Option manually with the value and text from DB. It's done! My code become like this:

```
<select class="shipping form-control" name="shipping_id">
     <option value="<?php echo $data['shippingId']; ?>" selected><?php echo $shipping['name']; ?></option>
</select>
```

But is there any problem/cause further? Because I think it's weird solution... (although it's work)